# Undefined variable: libros (View: C:\Users\CDS22\Desktop\Crud\resources\views\libros\index.blade.php) on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm receiving an array from my controller to my view to map it with the `@foreach` blade loop, but after an insertion into the database, when I want to redirect my app to the index blade document, this error appears:

This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $libro = new Libro;
    $libro->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $libro->save();
    return view('libros.index');
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($libros as $libro)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $libro->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $libro->titulo }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect that my controller method redirect send me to the view correctly, but everytime I enter a register to the database and the controller redirects me to my blade view, this error appears and I have to reload the page to enter into the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your store method you either have to redirect the user to the index page, or retrieve and pass all the `libros` array again.
The former way is preferred.

Assuming you have given a name to your route, you can do something like:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $libro = new Libro;
   $libro->titulo = $request->titulo;
   $libro->save();
   return redirect()->route('libros.index'); // replace libros.index with the index route name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you rewrite like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
//
$libro = new Libro;
$libro->titulo = $request->titulo;
$libro->save();
$libros = Libro::all()->get();
return view('libros.index', compact('libros'));
}
```